# Как получить GET переменную с пробелами?

Tags: php, html, mysql, get, ссылки

Есть ссылка `<a href="page.php?del=test test">link</a>`, в PHP ловлю ее из `$_GET["del"]` и пытаюсь по содержимому этой переменной удалить из базы поле с текстом `test test` но поле не удаляется! Из phpMyAdmin вручную этот запрос правильно отрабатывает вот я и пришел к выводу, что в $_GET["del"] хранится текст до первого пробела(естественно такого поля нет и запись не удаляется по этому). Как выйти из подобной ситуации?

Запрос к базе такой: `"DELETE FROM services WHERE service=$_GET[del]"`

Comment: `я и пришел к выводу, что в $_GET["del"] хранится текст до первого пробела` ну а что показывает консоль браузера, когда отправляется запрос? Или `echo  $_GET["del"]` Зачем гадать, если можно посмотреть?)

Comment: У php есть консоль?

Comment: Да... Но вы же на ссылку не из php нажимаете?

Comment: @perfect, да конечно php -a

Comment: @АлексейШиманский после нажатия ссылки все окей в адресной строке `page.php?del=test test` получается

Comment: @perfect консоль != адреснаяСтрокаБраузера =)  В браузере есть инструменты разработчика в которых есть много вкладок, в том числе "Сеть", в котором можно посмотреть что и как отправляется на сервер. В том числе гет/пост запрос ..... пользуйтесь этими инструментами при своей работе, они очень нужны и важны http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1608/ce/85a50b92708f.jpg

Comment: @perfect, прочитайте про SQL-инъекции. Ваш запрос к базе опасен.

Comment: @Visman да надо почитать, но в принципе у меня до подключения к базе написан процесс аутентификации.

Comment: @perfect, основное правило: нельзя доверять ни каким данным пришедшим со стороны. Есть у вас аутентификации, нет ее, тут не имеет значения.

Comment: @Visman , заинтриговали , откуда возьмутся сторонние данные если с базой работает проверенный пользователь...

Comment: @perfect, `данным пришедшим со стороны.` это данные извне скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в другом - вы не правильно выполняете запрос на удаление... нужно так:

```
"DELETE FROM services WHERE service='$_GET[del]'"
```

Подготавливать сам запрос для вставки в параметр GET (в ссылку), конечно желательно... но если у вас там просто текст без спецсимволов, то не обязательно.

**UPDATE**

Обязательно перед вставкой переменной в запрос необходимо сделать подготовку этой переменной, например:

```
$_GET['del'] = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['del']));
```

Используйте PDO.

А вообще, удалять данные по "тексту с пробелами" - плохой стиль. Правильно будет - передавать ID удаляемой записи и удалять по ID.

Comment: Вот так точно запрос не надо выполнять!

Comment: @Visman, почему? Есть разница от того где находятся экранирующие кавычки?

Comment: @Visman да ладно? Вы же опытный пользователь этого портала и знаете, что это плохой стиль давать подобного рода бесполезные комментарии. Дайте человеку рекомендацию использовать пдо или делать самостоятельно предподготовку переменной до помещения в запрос. Или что-то еще, если есть чем дополнить... (или вообще скажите, что удалять нужно по ID, а не "тексту с пробелами")

Comment: @Stanislav, я вам этот комментарий написал, как оценку вашего ответа. Автору вопроса же судя по ответам на комменты пофиг на безопасность.

Comment: @Visman , вы не правы , я последовал вашему совету и уже знаю что такое sql-инъекции и как с ними бороться. почему бы не принять совет если человек от души пытается помочь. Ну насчет пофигизма так ситуации то разные бывают. В моем случае я полное право даю удалять все данные из таблицы для проверенного пользователя и нет смысла в дополнительной защите, потому как все эти операции доступны ему из его интерфейса. Но за совет большое спасибо теперь буду иметь ввиду эти знания.

Comment: @Visman я согласен с вами. К сожалению, часто вижу вопросы, где нужно просто решение, и не глубже. Хотя, вы от себя, могли бы просто раскрыть суть своего комментария, т.е. не то что "Вот так точно запрос не надо выполнять!", а то, что "Было бы здорово так же уделить внимание безопасности..." . Ну это мое мнение относительно вашего первого комментария. Хотя, свой ответ поправлю, чтобы это порадовало ТС, вас и, возможно, других пользователей, у кого может возникнуть подобный вопрос.

Comment: @perfect, исходя из моего опыта, к сожалению, нужно проверять данные даже от "проверенных" пользователей.

Comment: @Stanislav, для меня программирование это философия. К примеру возьмем пустынное багги, эта та же обычная машина только со снятой всей защитой, зачем в пустыне защита от столкновения если врезаться просто в не во что, а горючего в пустыне нет. Так зачем тратить горючее на вес защиты? Тут налицо выигрыш в правильном распределении ресурсов. Так и в программировании из за усложнении кода усложняется процесс его сопровождения и лишняя трата и без того ограниченных ресурсов...

Comment: @perfect, иногда "усложнение" ведет к более легкому и удобному сопровождению. Например, небольшое усложнение, типа нормализации БД способствует ее большей структурированности и более легкому взаимодействию с ней. Иногда это может быть избыточно (например, когда мы для поиска храним лишние индексы и т.д.), но мы за счет этого решаем другие задачи. В коде, например, вы ожидаете или передаете какие-то массивы данных. Правильней создать дополнительный объект, в котором задать эти параметры через свойства с начальными значениями. А для передачи создавать объект, задавать ему свойства и передавать.

Comment: @Stanislav, в моем случае даже иногда не произойдет аварии, а добавится не нужный PDO код, который придется изучать при повторном чтении. Из вашего примера с нормализацией можно сделать отступление в том, что и с ней можно перестараться и она станет избыточной и будет тормозить программу (особенно это касается 4,5 форм).

Comment: @Stanislav Выглядит это как из примера моей реальной жизни: у меня есть друг который носит с собой водительские права потому что он себе вообразил что будет случай в котором однажды встретит водителя который потерял сознание и его нужно будет срочно довезти его в больницу на машине этого водителя, а итог был такой он однажды потерял права.

Comment: @perfect ваше сравнение с другом не правильно... конечно, вы можете писать код как хотите. Я программировать начал еще до школы, потом в школе продолжил, ездил на олимпиады, потом в институте, учился на программиста, и сейчас, после института, работаю программистом... на пхп пишу с 2003 года. Имея большой, по моим меркам, опыт в программировании могу сказать, что предложенные правила и стандарты совсем не лишние, и реально делают код более читабельным и удобно поддерживаемым. То что делаете вы - годится только для вас. Из двух путей "быстро" и "правильно" вы выбираете "быстро" - ваше право.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43671/discussion-between-perfect-and-stanislav).

Answer (score 5):

Обычно текст с пробелами и другими недопустимыми в запросах символами кодируется, либо при помощи функции `rawurlencode()`, которая заменяет пробел на последовательность `\%20`, либо при помощи функции `urlencode()`, которая заменяет пробел на плюс. В этом случае можно корректно передать данные через GET-параметр.

```
$del = rawurlencode('test test');
echo '<a href="page.php?del='.$del.'">link</a>';
```

Современные браузеры и серверы обычно осуществляют декодирование самостоятельно. Однако, если вам нужно в силу причин декодировать данные самостоятельно, для каждой из указанных выше функций имеется обратная: `rawurldecode()` и `rawdecode()`, соответственно.

Comment: подсмотрев ваш код, подставил одинарные кавычки и все заработало. Было <a href="page.php?del=test test"> а стало <a href="page.php?del='test test'">. В чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: Вероятно это уже от браузера зависит, у меня ваша ссылка в FireFox <a href="page.php?del=test test">link</a> нормально отработала, пробел был автоматически декодирован в %20, а вот так бы уже не сработало <a href=page.php?del=test test>link</a>, последний test рассматривался бы как атрибут тэга a. В любом случае не будет лишним явно кодировать пробел в %20, браузеры его декодируют, но строго говоря не обязаны это делать. Какой-нибудь мобильный браузер может вести себя по-другому.